# Classification of image (in interval) of polynomial (non constant)

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polynomials, continuity

There is something I am trying to prove:

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a nonconstant polynomial. Show that the image of the function is either the real line, $[a, \infty)$, or $(-\infty,a]$ for some $a\in\mathbb R$.

Here I tried to separate them to odd and even powers of polynomials, and intuitively, I see why it will be true. I am unable to make it rigorous (I thought about using the max/min value theorem for the even cases but not sure exactly how it will work). We probably use the intermediate value theorem for the odd case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** If the degree is odd, prove that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} P(x)= \pm \infty \\ \lim_{x \to -\infty} P(x)= \mp \infty$$

Now, for each real value, by the above $P(x)$ takes a larger and smaller value, thus by IVT it takes the value.

If the degree is even,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} P(x)= \lim_{x \to -\infty} P(x)= \pm \infty$$

Now, deending on the sign, you can find a $c$ such that outside $[-c,c]$ the Polynomial is always larger/smaller than $P(0)$.

Use the fact that on $[-c,c]$ the polynomial attains his absolute min and max.